# Using a list to specify pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
pandas.DataFrame(columns=('code', 'name', ['aa', 'ab']))
```

I would like to create a dataframe, using a list to specify some of the column names, but I get this error:

```
*** TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an iterable such as a list.  Remember that `['a'] + ['b'] = ['a', 'b']`.

```
columns=['code', 'name'] + ['aa', 'ab'] 
>>> columns
['code', 'name', 'aa', 'ab']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple rather than a list:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(columns=('code', 'name', ('aa', 'ab')))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [code, name, (aa, ab)]
Index: []
```

Dictionary keys must be 'hashable', which means that given the same key value you will always get the same response (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), even if the values are stored in different memory locations.

Consider the following:

```
>>> hash(('a','b')), hash(('a','b'))
(-3816799034373630758, -3816799034373630758)

>>> id(('a','b')), id(('a','b'))
(4329654248, 4369596640)
```

The two items have different ids (that is, they are stored in different locations in memory) but they have the same hash value; with the hash of a tuple is implemented using the hashes of the bits that make up the tuple.

Lists do not have a `__hash__` method defined.  Even if they did, the hash value would not be the same throughout the lifetime of the object.  That's because a list is mutable; adding a new element to the list would change its hash value.